# Dynamic sql in openrowset error "is not a valid identifier."

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

I am getting a is not a valid identifier error.  I tried tweaking the quotes and still not able to get it right.

TIY

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DynamicQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(CovCode)
FROM (SELECT  distinct
    CovCode

 FROM Construct.dbo.View_Claim_SummaryPTS4PTS5Diamond where system in (4,5)) AS ClaimSummary

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT vehicleid, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM Construct.dbo.View_Claim_SummaryPTS4PTS5Diamond
    PIVOT(max(Claim_Exp_Nbr) 
          FOR CovCode IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

Set @DynamicQuery = 'Select * into #tmpcde from openrowset(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=HPL-DSQL2\HPLDSQL2;Trusted_Connection=yes;'', '''Exec @DynamicPivotQuery''')'
exec (@DynamicQuery)

Select * from #tmpcde
```

Comment: `print @DynamicPivotQuery`

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want it like this:

```
Set @DynamicQuery = 'Select * into #tmpcde from openrowset(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=HPL-DSQL2\HPLDSQL2;Trusted_Connection=yes;'', '''+@DynamicPivotQuery+''')';
```